# Microsoft Sync Framework with Offline HTML5 database syncronization

Tags: android, microsoft-sync-framework, offlineapps

I have referred more sites for `steps to create Offline HTML 5 database synchronization in Android using Microsoft Sync Framework`. Could anybody can redirect me to the site required?

I followed this

http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/documentation

but in the **step 2 -> SyncFramework should be oppened as project in Eclipse.**
Where the source of SyncFramework  will be for android?

**Note: I have installed SyncSDK-v2.1-x86-ENU**

Answer (score 0):

that project is referring to Sync Framework Toolkit, have a look at it here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e

you will also find a HTML5 sample there...